# How can we format the data into table format using perl

Tags: perl, format

I have written a omnimark program to get the required tags in the output file.But i have a problem with format of this output data.So what should i do to put the below output data into table format using perl.

**Output from Omnimark program - Input to Perl Program :**

```
2.01[1] <hst u="61130263" c="" r="" st="">
<title>Holmes v. Cheney
<dkt>5-2652
<dte>19620000
<ct>Ark
<refs>234 Ark 503, 352 SW2d 943
</hst>  9
```

**Expected:**

```
 2.01[1]    <hst u="61130263" c="" r="" st="">              9
            <title>Holmes v. Cheney
            <dkt>5-2652
            <dte>19620000
            <ct>Ark
            <refs>234 Ark 503, 352 SW2d 943
            </hst>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use [`Text::Table`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Table;

my $data = [
    "2.01[1]",
    qq{<hst u="61130263" c="" r="" st="">\n<title>Holmes v. Cheney\n<dkt>5-2652\n<dte>19620000\n<ct>Ark\n<refs>234 Ark 503, 352 SW2d 943\n</hst>},
    9,
];

my $tb = Text::Table->new();
$tb->load($data);
print $tb;
```

Outputs:

```
2.01[1] <hst u="61130263" c="" r="" st=""> 9
        <title>Holmes v. Cheney             
        <dkt>5-2652                         
        <dte>19620000                       
        <ct>Ark                             
        <refs>234 Ark 503, 352 SW2d 943     
        </hst>
```

Comment: Miller : So if the output contains like this in many number then can u tell me how can this be done. .. Your help is highly appreciated ...

Comment: @Praveen you need to write a little parser that separates your input into the first column, the main body of text, and the last digit. You can then pass that data into Text::Table for formatting.